# Look up value from column in table and interpolate in rows (python pandas scipy)

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I am having trouble with a program that will first look up a date in another data frame, and then interpolate a certain value along the rows.

Problem:
Let the original data frames look like this:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"date":["06/24/2014","06/25/2014","06/26/2014"], "value":[2, 4, 6]})

B = pd.DataFrame({"date":["06/25/2014","06/26/2014","06/24/2014"], "1":[0.1, 0.5, 0.9],"3":[0.2, 0.6, 1.0],"5":[0.3, 0.7, 1.1],"7":[0.4, 0.8, 1.2]})
```

The idea is that the program should first find the row in B that matches with A by "date" and them interpolate using the names of the columns as the x_value and the values in the row as y_value.

The output should look like this:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"date":["06/24/2014","06/25/2014","06/26/2014"], "value":[2, 4, 6], "interp":[0.95,0.25, 0.75]})
```

---

My approach so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

A = pd.DataFrame({"date":["06/24/2014","06/25/2014","06/26/2014"], "value":[2, 4, 6]})

B = pd.DataFrame({"date":["06/25/2014","06/26/2014","06/24/2014"], "1":[0.1, 0.5, 0.9],"3":[0.2, 0.6, 1.0],"5":[0.3, 0.7, 1.1],"7":[0.4, 0.8, 1.2]})

# Define x as the names of the columns 
x_value = (1,3,5,7)

#Define the interpolation function as follows

def interp(row):
    idx = B[B['date'] == row['date']].index.tolist()[0] #get indx from B
    z_value = [] #get values from row in B
    for i in range(1,5):
        z_value.append(float(B.iloc[idx][i]))
    tuple(z_value)
    f_linear = interp1d(x_value,z_value) #define interpolation function
    y_il = f_linear(row['value'])
    return y_il
```

Finally, I would apply the function to each row this way:

```
A['interp']=A.apply(interp, axis=1)
```

I get the following output. Is there a better way to do this??

```
>>> A
         date interp  value
0  06/24/2014   0.95      2
1  06/25/2014   0.25      4
2  06/26/2014   0.75      6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really only want the *select* values, this will give it to you. Note, I make use of the `groupby` function so that I only have to create a `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` call once per `date`

The data munging:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"date":["06/24/2014","06/25/2014","06/26/2014"], "value":[2, 4, 6]})
B = pd.DataFrame({"date":["06/25/2014","06/26/2014","06/24/2014"], 
                  "1":[0.1, 0.5, 0.9],"3":[0.2, 0.6, 1.0],"5":[0.3, 0.7, 1.1],"7":[0.4, 0.8, 1.2]})
B = B.set_index('date').T
B.index = B.index.astype(int)
```

Then the actual work

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import pandas as pd

def interped(series,targets):
    x,y = zip(*series.items())
    f = interp1d(x,y)
    return [(i,f(i)) for i in targets]

def getResults(dfA, dfB):
    grouped = dfA.groupby('date')
    res = []
    for key in grouped.groups:
        targets = grouped.get_group(key)['value'].values
        values = interped(dfB[key], targets)
        res.extend([(key, target, value) for target,value in values])

    return pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["date", "target", "interp"])

getResults(A, B)
```

Outputs:

```
    date    target  interp
0   06/24/2014  2   0.95
1   06/26/2014  6   0.75
2   06/25/2014  4   0.25
```

---

AND if you insist on calling `A.apply` ....

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

A = pd.DataFrame({"date":["06/24/2014","06/25/2014","06/26/2014"], "value":[2, 4, 6]})
B = pd.DataFrame({"date":["06/25/2014","06/26/2014","06/24/2014"], 
                  "1":[0.1, 0.5, 0.9],"3":[0.2, 0.6, 1.0],"5":[0.3, 0.7, 1.1],"7":[0.4, 0.8, 1.2]})
B = B.set_index('date').T
B.index = B.index.astype(int)


def getRowApplyFunc():
    funcs = {}
    def interped(row):
        date = row['date']
        target = row['value']
        if date in funcs:
            interpFunc = funcs[date]
        else:
            x,y = zip(*B[date].items())
            interpFunc = interp1d(x,y)
            funcs[date] = interpFunc
        return interpFunc(target)
    return interped

A['interpd'] = A.apply(getRowApplyFunc(), axis=1)
A
```

Also outputs:

```
    date    value   interpd
0   06/24/2014  2   0.95
1   06/25/2014  4   0.25
2   06/26/2014  6   0.75
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. Are you implying that using "apply" would not be the best approach here? I have to admit that my function above was very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's not a coincidence that the  values to be interpolated are the 'missing' values in B. If that's the case, you don't need the `A` dataframe at all.

```
B = pd.DataFrame({"date":["06/25/2014","06/26/2014","06/24/2014"], 
                  "1":[0.1, 0.5, 0.9],"3":[0.2, 0.6, 1.0],"5":[0.3, 0.7, 1.1],"7":[0.4, 0.8, 1.2]})
B = B.set_index('date').T
B.index = B.index.astype(int)
B = B.reindex(range(1,8))
B
```

So now, `B` is

```
date    06/25/2014  06/26/2014  06/24/2014
1   0.1     0.5     0.9
2   NaN     NaN     NaN
3   0.2     0.6     1.0
4   NaN     NaN     NaN
5   0.3     0.7     1.1
6   NaN     NaN     NaN
7   0.4     0.8     1.2
```

And so now we can directly apply [pandas DataFrame interpolate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

```
res = B.interpolate()
res.loc[[2,4,6]]
```

Outputs:

```
date    06/25/2014  06/26/2014  06/24/2014
2   0.15    0.55    0.95
4   0.25    0.65    1.05
6   0.35    0.75    1.15
```

Granted that from there, you will have to select your desired data.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I appreciate your help. I think i can so something with this.  -- In general, my data frame A has several thousand rows. I think your solution would give me a data frame with a few thousand columns and a few thousand rows